# git remote over ftp: "Can't open refs ..."

Tags: xcode, git, ftp

I'm having a cloned repository on my NAS. All the files are in there.
Now I would like to add this repository as a remote to my Xcode-project (I cloned from).
I tried using Xcode's UI and the terminal, both failed, so I tracked down the problem with Wireshark and it shows that "refs" can't be found:

[image]

I can access the refs-file with ftp over the browser and with finder, it's definitely there and healthy with all subfolders included.
The given path is ending with /.git, the /info is accessed automatically.

If I try to set the given path to ../.git/refs it also can enter the path but than fails to open /info which is ok because /info isn't in /refs.

I can't find out what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you haven't run `git update-server-info` on that repository. That command must be run after any update to a repository for that update to be available over any of the dump protocols, where git isn't involved on the server side of the fetch. That command will create or update the `info/refs` file.

You stated that you can access `refs` manually, but that sounds like you're looking at the `refs` directory at the top of the repository, since you state that you see subfolders. The output from wireshark shows that it's failing to open `info/refs`, since the 4th line shows that it successfully changed into the `info` directory. And the `refs` in there should be a plain-text file.

Since you state that the repository is on a NAS, if at all possible I'd advise mounting that as a remote file system, and clone from that rather than using FTP. Using FTP you'll need to remember to run that command after every update to the repository. That wouldn't be necessary if you let git have direct access to the files.